# Mitm proxy doesn't capture windows universal app ssl traffic

Tags: windows, mitmproxy

As the title says, I couldn't get mitm proxy to log ssl traffic of windows apps.
I tested an app working with ssl on both Android and Windows + Windows mobile.
Even in fiddler, I exempted the app but it couldn't track the requests either.
as I was searching I saw someone using a program (I couldn't find) to track the requests from a process called WinUAPEntry.exe that's used by universal apps for requests.
Any solutions?

- I have installed the mitm proxy's ssl cerifitcaion
- I have set the wifi proxy to the ip of the device where mitmproxy is running
- I have forwarded the 80, 443 in iptables as mentioned in mitmproxy tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching a month I found out Windows Apps bypass proxy settings, tested on both Desktop and Mobile. I came up with solutions like MAC IP binding and setting NIC Ip of the host as a gateway but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this running with https://loopback.codeplex.com/. This is the same as Fiddler's EnableLoopback Utility though, so if that didn't work YMMV.

Comment: I've tried that too, my problems is only with the https requests. I can see http requests of other apps with fiddler and others. Thanks